# How to create synthetic Timeseries Datasets having Seasonality & Trend?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I need to create a few fictional Timeseries datasets of 15 min intervals from a particular start date to an end date.

These need to have some seasonality/noise and also have trends, such that they look like the following:

[image]

I'll need to have this in the form of a dataframe eventually (with the X & Y values) so that I can export it into an excel file.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that arithmetic is the best solution for you. You can play with some random variables, sinus, ... to get what you want.

For example we can have this :
[image]

```
x = np.linspace(0, 50, 200)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.rand(len(x))*noise_strength 
y[100:] += x[:100]/2 + y[100]
```

or this :
[image]

```
x = np.linspace(0, 50, 200)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.rand(len(x))*noise_strength + x/5
y[:100] -= 5
```